# I am trying to put as a constants some methods from jodaTime

Tags: java, constants, jodatime

I am trying to put as a constants some methods from jodaTime. These are the methods:

```
jodaTime.getMonthOfYear()
jodaTime.getDayOfMonth()
jodaTime.getYearOfCentury()
```

I Searched around the packages and classes but i couldnt find the way to access to those methods.

I want to know how can i access those methods to put them in constants, for example `public static final Object DAY_OF_MONTH=org.joda.time....`

Comment: You've posted a *lot* of code, but not given a clear indication of what you're trying to do, or what happens at the moment. Please reduce this to a [mcve] to make it clear what the problem is. (And take the time to format your code, and ideally translate variable names etc to English, as this is an English site - the more you can do to make your question easy to read, the better.)

Comment: I updated the question @JonSkeet

Comment: A method can't be stored in a constant. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Now there's basically *no* code - that's still not a [mcve], is it? Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to store the year, month, and day of the startup time of your application? I can't think of any other use for this type of code. The implementation is simple; here's some pseudocode:

```
class MyClass {
    static final Object DAY_OF_MONTH;
    static {
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        DAY_OF_MONTH = now.getDayOfMonth();
    }
}
```

If you want to refer to the methods themselves, you can use lambdas to something more like this:

```
class MyClass {
    static final Supplier<Integer> DAY_OF_MONTH;
    static {
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        DAY_OF_MONTH = now::getDayOfMonth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've defined `DAY_OF_MONTH` and `DAY_OF_YEAR`, you can pass them in as lambdas:

```
Map<Integer, Runnable> commands = new HashMap<>();
commands.put(DAY_OF_MONTH, () -> jodaTime.getDayOfMonth());
commands.put(DAY_OF_YEAR, () -> jodaTime.getDayOfYear());
```

OR

You can save off `Method` in your `Map` and use reflection.

`Map<Method, ValueIForgotSinceYouDeletedCode> map = new HashMap<>()`